# Who are the animators responsible for Madoka Magica?

Tags: madoka-magica

I'm curious who was responsible for the animation in Madoka Magica, especially the labyrinth  sequences. I can find information about the illustrators of the manga, but I'm wondering about the anime. I want to know if they were influenced by Bill Sienkiewicz, because I feel like I'm having a flashback to early New Mutants when I watch those sequences. Who are these animators?

Comment: I don't think this quite answers your question, but the group [**Inu Curry**](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=75181) was primarily responsible for the _design_ of the labyrinth sequences in Madoka Magica. I'm not sure whether or not they actually participated in any of the actual animation.

Comment: @senshin - Thanks, I'll try to follow up on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As senshin answered, the design of the witch mazes was done by Inu Curry, so considering the motivation is about where they might have inspired themselves in, I'm pretty sure that answers you quetion, but for some supplementary info if you want:

http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Madoka_Magica_Staff_and_Cast#SHAFT

It has all the entire animation staff that handled Madoka Magica, including which episodes certain animator directors were responsible for, etc..